# checking if an array is in an array

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to validate whether or not an array is listed in an array.
I am trying to add a product name and url to an session, the session will contain all the products visited by a visitor, but I don't want it to add the same product twice, hence the validation. So if the product is already in the array, I want it to do nothing, but if it doesn't already belong to the array, it needs to be added. This is as far as I got so far. The only issue seems to be the validation.

```
$viewed_product_url = $viewed_base.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if(!isset($_SESSION['products'])) {
$_SESSION['products'] = array('product'=>$products_name,'url'=>$viewed_product_url);
} else {
$found = false;
foreach($_SESSION['products'] as $each_item) {
    while(list($key,$value)=each($each_item)) {
        if($key == 'product' && $value == $products_name) {
            $found = true;
        }
    }
}
if($found==false){
echo 'found';
    $_SESSION['products'][] =    array('product'=>$products_name,'url'=>$viewed_product_url);
}
}
```

these are the errors I am getting

Warning: Variable passed to each() is not an array or object in C:\xampp\htdocs\customers\msl\product.php on line 10

Warning: Variable passed to each() is not an array or object in C:\xampp\htdocs\customers\msl\product.php on line 10
found

So I just want to know how you can check if an array is already in an multivariate array. Or if there are any other alternatives to achieving what I want here.

Comment: You're treating `$_SESSION['products']` as a 2-dimensional array. But when you initialize it, it's just a 1-dimensional associative array.

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
$_SESSION['products'] = array('product'=>$products_name,'url'=>$viewed_product_url);
```

to:

```
$_SESSION['products'] = array(array('product'=>$products_name,'url'=>$viewed_product_url));
```

so that you get a 2-dimensional array.

However, I think this is a poor data structure. You should make `$_SESSION['products']` an associative array, whose key is the product name. So you add elements to it with:

```
$_SESSION['products'][$products_name] = $viewed_product_url;
```

and you find products with:

```
$found = isset($_SESSION['products'][$products_name]);
```

Answer (score 0):

check with `is_array` like

```
if(is_array($_SESSION['products']))
```

and then you can go with `foreach`

Comment: `Traversable` objects yield false in `is_array`

Answer (score 0):

is_array() function will help you..
  http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-array.php

Answer (score 0):

`$each_item` is not an array. That is the reason for the error.

Try this

```
$viewed_product_url = $viewed_base.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if(!isset($_SESSION['products'])) {
$_SESSION['products'] = array('product'=>$products_name,'url'=>$viewed_product_url);
} else {
$found = false;  
if (in_array($viewed_product_url, $_SESSION['products'])) { {
        $found = true;
    }
}
}
if($found==false){
echo 'found';
$_SESSION['products'][] = array('product'=>$products_name,'url'=>$viewed_product_url);
```

}
}